# Oracle bad bind variable , Statement ignored and one more error

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm new in Oracle, and I try to write my first real trigger, but have some errors... :(

this is my code:

```
create or replace TRIGGER CUSTERP_ABILITYVALUECODES_TRG
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF CODE OR DELETE ON ABILITYVALUECODES
REFERENCING NEW AS newest OLD AS oldest
FOR EACH ROW
declare s varchar2(4096);
BEGIN
    if :oldest.CODE <> :newest.CODE then
    if :newest.CODE is null then
        s := 'NULL';
    else
        s := ASCIISTR(:newest.CODE);
    end if;
    s:= utl_url.escape(s);
    if :newest.CODE is null then
        CUSTERP_TRG('T_ABILITYVALUECODES', concat('C_CODE;KEY: ABILITYVALUE = ', :oldest.ABILITYVALUE,  ',OLD:', :oldest.CODE, ',NEW:', s));
    else
        CUSTERP_TRG('T_ABILITYVALUECODES', concat('C_CODE;KEY: ABILITYVALUE =',  :newest.ABILITYVALUE,  ',OLD:', :oldest.CODE, ',NEW:', s));
    end if;
end if;
END;
```

I'm getting these errors:
Error(11,13): PL/SQL: Statement ignored (seems like it refers to s:=...)
Error(11,53): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CONCAT'

if I do like that:

```
s := 'NULL';
```

I get: Error(6,13): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'S'

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear in error message. `Error is in concat function that you are using to call method- CUSTERP_TRG.`

`CONCAT` function takes only two string arguments.

If you want to concat more then two arguments you need to use CONCAT function multiple times.

You are using Oracle so simply you should use pipes - `||` for concatenation.

I am assuming that ABILITYVALUE and CODE column are of type CHAR or VARCHAR or VARCHAR2. If they are INT then you may need to use TO_CHAR.

Replace if-else block in your TRIGGER with below code.

```
if :newest.CODE is null then
  CUSTERP_TRG( 'T_ABILITYVALUECODES', 'C_CODE;KEY: ABILITYVALUE = ' || :oldest.ABILITYVALUE ||  ',OLD:' || :oldest.CODE || ',NEW:' || s );
else
  CUSTERP_TRG( 'T_ABILITYVALUECODES', 'C_CODE;KEY: ABILITYVALUE =' || :newest.ABILITYVALUE ||  ',OLD:' || :oldest.CODE || ',NEW:' || s );
end if;
```

Comment: Sure. Welcome. :)